# Áudio com os primeiros 30 segundos mudo

Tags: php, vídeo

estou tendo usar este código mais sem sucesso porem no terminal funciona perfeitamente o que pode ser?

```
exec("ffmpeg -i musica.mp3 -af "volume=enable='between(t,0,30)':volume=0" result.mp3 2> log.txt");
```

A música esta na pasta do php, inclusive uso outros comandos no arquivos com sucesso. O servidor é linux, o comando roda perfeitamente pelo terminal putty. mas precisava rodar pelo php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um erro estranho, não sei como não deu erro de syntaxe, mas aqui você usou aspas dentro das aspas do primeiro argumento do `exec`:

```
... -af "volume=enable='between(t,0,30)':volume=0" ...
        ^ - Aqui                                 ^ aqui
```

Você deve escapar eles assim:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i musica.mp3 -af \"volume=enable='between(t,0,30)':volume=0\" result.mp3 2> log.txt");
```

Também recomendo que use `escapeshellarg` com o `exec` (se for Like-unix) e use o caminho absoluto por precaução.

Deve ficar assim:

```
//Pega o caminho todo do script atual
define('FULL_PATH', rtrim(strtr(dirname(__FILE__), '\\', '/'), '/') . '/');

$sourcePath = FULL_PATH . 'musica.mp3';
$savePath   = FULL_PATH . 'result.mp3';
$params     = escapeshellarg('"volume=enable=\'between(t,0,30)\':volume=0"');

exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $sourcePath . ' -af ' . $params . ' ' . $savePath . ' 2> log.txt');
```

Comment: Guilherme você é 10 cara... funcionou perfeitamente... muito obrigado...